# meaning of (\/?) in regex / is (\w+)([^>]*?) a redundancy?

Tags: javascript, regex

this regular expression should match an html start tag, I think.

`var results = html.match(/<(\/?)(\w+)([^>]*?)>/);`

I see it should first capture the `<`, but then I am confused what this capture `(\/?)` accomplishes. Am I correct in reasoning that the `([^>]*?)>` searches for every character except `>` >= 0 times? If so, why is the `(\w+)` capture necessary? Doesn't it fall within the purview of `[^>]*?`

Comment: it finds end tags, you know </b> instead of <b>... the \w captures the tag name to a parameter to use in replacement instead of bundling it with the attrib section... for a match you don't need it, but if help the regexp if recycled into a replace()...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take it token by token:

- `/` begin regex literal
- `<` match a literal `<`
- `(\/?)` match 0 or 1 (`?`) literal `/`, which is escaped by the `\`
- `(\w+)` match one or more "word characters"
- `([^>]*?)` lazily* match zero or more (`*?`) of anything that is not a `>`
- `>` match a literal `>`
- `/` end regex literal

lazily* - adding "?" after a repetition quantifier will make it perform lazily, meaning the regex will match the preceding token the minimum number of times. See the [documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

So essentially this regular expression will match "<", potentially followed by a "/", followed by any number of letters, digits, or underscores, followed by anything that is not a ">", and finally followed by a ">".

That being said, the token `(\w+)` is not redundant, as it ensures there is at least one word character in between `<` and `>`.

Please be aware that [attempting to parse HTML with regular expressions is generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: The "?" is not redundant, in case there is more than one html tag on the same line!

Comment: @TomLord I have edited the answer to include what the `*?` actually does. Learned something new myself :)

Comment: @TomLord why is it useful to have this match be "lazy"?

Comment: @TomLord, I beg to differ. Even with `[^>]*`, it won't match multiple tags because it has to go through a closing angle bracket (`>`) to do so. So yes, the `?` is actually redundant here.

Comment: Actually, I take that back - it *is* actually redundant. But let me explain... Suppose the code had said (.*?) instead of ([^>]*?). (This is what I thought it basically was doing, at a glance!) Compare what happens with/without the "?": http://www.rubular.com/r/U5VtGkFY3q  http://www.rubular.com/r/Fsig98EoDg

Comment: In that second (bad) example, the .* operator is being "greedy" (as opposed to "lazy"), and is matching **as much as it can**, up to the final ">".

Comment: In the actual code, however, this is not a problem because even a "greedy" ([^>]*) will only match up to the first ">".

Answer (score 4):

Using the power of debuggex to generate you an image :)

```
<(\/?)(\w+)([^>]*?)>
```

Will be evaluated like this

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/hnhZ3pDQrgvXlpHg)

As you can see, it matches HTML-tags (opening *and* closing tags). The regex contains three capture groups, capturing the following:

1. `(\/?)` existence of `/` (it's a closing tag, if present)
2. `(\w+)` name of the tag
3. `([^>]*?)` everything else until the tag closes (e.g. attributes)

This way it matches `<a href="#">`. Interestingly it does not match `<a data-fun="fun>nofun">` correctly because it stops at the `>` within the `data-fun` attribute. Although (I think) `>` [is valid in an attribute value](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-AttValue).

Another funny thing is, that the tag-name capture, does not capture all theoretically valid XHTML tags. XHTML allows `Letter | Digit | '.' | '-' | '_' | ':' | ..` (source: [XHTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-NameChar)). `(\w+)`, however, does not match `.`, `-`, and `:`. An imaginary `<.foobar>` tag will not be matched by this regex. This should not have any real life impact, though.

You see that parsing HTML using RgExes is a risky thing. You might be better of with a HTML parser.

Answer (score 3):

`(\/?)` matches, and catches any closing tag, such as `</i>` maybe, or `</strong>` if you're familiar with them?

Another thing to note is that `\w` is really the character class `[a-zA-Z_\d]`, so that other characters like `=`, `"`, etc are not matched, and will however be matched by `[^>]`. And yes, you are correct about that bit.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, it won't match the regex. It was just as an example for the forward slash, but I guess I'll just use another =/

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what bit I am correct about though

Comment: @thomas This bit: "Am I correct in reasoning that the `([^>]*?)>` searches for every character except `>` >= 0 times?" :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your last question, `(\w+)` and `([^>]*?)` are not redundant. They both serve important functions in the expression.

This expression finds start or end tags.

`(\/?)` matches a `/`, but the `?` makes it optional.

`(\w+)` matches word characters, intended to match the tag name here.

`([^>]*?)` is intended to match attributes.

So if you had the string `<div class="text">`,

The `(\w+)` in the expression would match `div` and the `([^>]*?)` would match `class="text"`

Comment: It's picky, but the `([^>]*?)` actually matches ` class="text"` (including the space after 'div'). :)

Comment: @tessi You're right, and if you edit my post, you can see I have the space in there, but it gets removed when it is displayed. If someone can suggest a way to get the space to display, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Har, that's funny. I will never blame you again because of that (specific) space then ;)

Comment: Agreed. `([^>]*?)` *by itself* is not redundant.  However in `(\w+)([^>]*?)>` the lazy operation *is* redundant.  The regex has to match one or more "word" characters (which aren't ">"), followed by zero or more non right pointing angle bracket characters, followed by a right pointing angle bracket character.  Greedy or not, it has to match that character (class) sequence exactly.  Lazy only applies when the types of characters you are matching may also match what follows, like in `.*?<`;  `.` can match "<".

Comment: @JayC That may be. I think that sentence in my answer wasn't clear, hopefully the edit is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Demo (in ruby, not javascript, but it makes no difference): http://www.rubular.com/r/bhw2O28qUr

To summarise, it's to capture end tags.

Comment: and beginning tags it seems. Thanks for the answer and the cool test site!

Comment: I meant "end tags" as in, <html> is a begin tag and </html> is an end tag.